# Regex checking Skus

Tags: regex

I need to set has_online to true if the sku has OL in it, has_WB to tru if the sku has WB in it and has_classroom to true if the sku doesn't have WB or OL but otherwise matches

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}OL/', $sku))       $has_online      = true;
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}WB/', $sku))       $has_WB          = true;
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]{2}/', $sku)) $has_classroom   = true;
```

I'm having problems with the has_classroom portion. It also sets has_classroom when it is a OL or WB course as well.

Skus are formatted like this:

```
20120531TXCP
20120531OLCP
20120531WBCP
20120531FLAO
20120531NVAR
```

I redid it like this but am not happy with it.

```
$wb_course = preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}WB/', $sku);
$ol_course = preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}OL/', $sku);
if ($ol_course)                                 $has_online      = true;
if ($wb_course)                                 $has_WB          = true;
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]{2}/', $sku) 
    && !$wb_course 
    && !$ol_course)                             $has_classroom   = true;
```

Any ideas that can help me realize this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try else if?

```
  if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}OL/', $sku))       $has_online      = true;   
  else if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}WB/', $sku))       $has_WB     = true;   
  else if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]{2}/', $sku)) $has_classroom   = true;
```

Comment: Actually, never thought about that...DUH!